# How can I understand histeq of matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm trying to understand what histeq function of MATLAB with the following matlab code.

```
clear all

S = imread('pout.tif');
[O,P] = histeq(S)
```

But I can't understand P meaning, I found that the following description.

```
[J,T] = histeq(I) returns the grayscale transformation T that maps gray levels in the image I to gray levels in J.
```

When I see [histeq output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7fzE.jpg), I can separate 3 part to A, B, C, as you can see that.

How Do I understand what exactly that have meaning which in A, B and C?

Answer (score 0):

In the X axis of your image you have the pixel intensity, which goes from 0 to 255 (8 bits), and in the Y axis a percentage.

What the image shows for a given point is the resulting intensity in `O` (in percentage of 255) for an intensity in `S`. So for example, in your case the pixels with intensity less than 70 in `S` (what you called part A) would have intensity 0*255 in `O`, and the pixels above 150 (part C) will have intensity 1*255. The intermediate intensities (part B) will have a value that is the Y axis value multiplied by 255 (for example, intensity 100 in `S` will have intensity 0.4*255 in `O`).

I hope my explanation is clear enough.